# Сканирование нескольких подсетей

Tags: perl, snmp

У меня есть скрипт *lldp2dot*, автор [sergiusk](http://forum.dlink.ru/viewtopic.php?t=156053)
Мне требуется дополнить функционал, но с автором я не могу связаться.
В данный момент скрипт может обрабатывать только 1 подсеть.
Например, `192.168.212.1-192.168.212.50`
Нужно чтобы была возможность сканировать как минимум 2 подсети: `192.168.212.1-192.168.212.50` и `10.111.1.1-10.111.1.100`.

Сам скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Topology Discovery, lldp2dot for FTTB by SERGIUS, v2.6.1 beta

use lib "./libs";

# use strict;
# use warnings;
use Net::SNMP;
use SNMP_Session;
use SNMP_util;
use Net::Ping;
use iptools;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use DateTime;

my $ping=Net::Ping->new();
my %hosts:shared=();
my $maxThreads=100;
my %lldpmapout = ();
my $mgmtvlans;
my $snmpcommunity = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
my %edges = ();
my %edges2 = ();
my %database = ();
my %snmplldpnei_hash = ();
my $i;
my $edgesid = 0;
my $edgesid2 = 0;
# Объявляем переменные
my $today = DateTime->now; # Определяем текущую дату


my @scanRange=(
    "10.111.1.4-10.111.1.40"    
);

foreach my $rangeS (@scanRange)
    {
    my @range=split /-/,$rangeS;
    my $startIP=iptools::IPtodec($range[0]);
    my $endIP=iptools::IPtodec($range[1]);
    for (my $i=$startIP;$i<=$endIP;$i++)
        {
        $_->join() foreach (threads->list(threads::joinable));
        if (threads->list(threads::all)>$maxThreads)
            {
            print "thread count > limit, joining\n";
            while(threads->list(threads::all)>$maxThreads)
                {
                $_->join() foreach (threads->list(threads::joinable));
                }
            }
        threads->create(\&pingDec,$i);
        }
        while(threads->list(threads::all))
        {
        $_->join() foreach (threads->list(threads::joinable));
        }

    foreach $iphost (keys %hosts)
        {
        print "get sysObjct.0 from $iphost... \n";
        }

    foreach $iphost (keys %hosts)
        {
        my $snmpsession;
        my $snmperror;
        my $snmptemp;
        my $snmpsysobject;
        my $snmplocalmac;
        my $snmplocation;
        my $snmpsysname;
        my $snmpvid;
        my %snmptemp = ();  
        my $request;
        my $id;
        my $sysobject;
        my $localmac;
        my $syslocation;
        my $sysname;
        my %snmpvlans = ();
        my $vlanid;
        my $snmploopback;
        my $fw;

        $syslocation = "";
        $localmac = "";
        $uptime = "";
        $sysname = "";
        my $firmware = "";
        $sysobject = "";
        $network = "";
        $vlanid = "";
        my $serial = "";

        print "get sysObjct.0 from $iphost... ";

        my ($snmpsession, $snmperror) = Net::SNMP -> session(
        -timeout => 1,
        -retries => 1,
        -hostname => $iphost,
        -community => $snmpcommunity,
        -translate => [-timeticks => 0x0]
        );

        #sysObject.0
        my $snmptemp = $snmpsession->get_request('.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0');
        if (ref($snmptemp))
            {
            my %snmpsysobjectid = %{$snmptemp};

            foreach my $values (values %snmpsysobjectid)
                {$sysobjectid = $values;}

            #default
            $id = 0;
            # 1-99 tkd
            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.6486.800.1.1.2.2.4.1.1")
                {$id = 1;$sysobject = "Alcatel-Lucent OmniStack LS 6224";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.171.10.113.1.5")
                {$id = 2;$sysobject = "D-Link DES-3200-26";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.171.10.63.6")
                {$id = 3;$sysobject = "D-Link DES-3028";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.171.10.64.1")
                {$id = 4;$sysobject = "D-Link DES-3526";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.171.10.113.1.1")
                {$id = 5;$sysobject = "D-Link DES-3200-10";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.171.10.64.2")
                {$id = 6;$sysobject = "D-Link DES-3550";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.171.10.105.3")
                {$id = 7;$sysobject = "D-Link DES-3552";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.171.10.113.1.3")
                {$id = 8;$sysobject = "D-Link DES-3200-28";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.171.10.113.5.1")
                {$id = 9;$sysobject = "D-Link DES-3200-28-C1";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.171.10.113.1.2")
                {$id = 10;$sysobject = "D-Link DES-3200-18";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.171.10.113.1.4")
                {$id = 11;$sysobject = "D-Link DES-3200-28F";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.171.10.113.9.1")
                {$id = 12;$sysobject = "D-Link DES-3200-52";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.171.10.116.2")
                {$id = 13;$sysobject = "D-Link DES-1228/ME";}

            # 100-999 agg
            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.6486.800.1.1.2.1.7.1.10")
                {$id = 100;$sysobject = "Alcatel-Lucent OmniSwitch 6850-U24X";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.171.10.70.8")
                {$id = 101;$sysobject = "D-Link DGS-3627G";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.171.10.120.1")
                {$id = 101;$sysobject = "D-Link DGS-6604";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.171.10.101.1")
                {$id = 102;$sysobject = "D-Link DGS-3200-10";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.171.10.70.9")
                {$id = 103;$sysobject = "D-Link DGS-3612g";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.207.1.4.149")
                {$id = 104;$sysobject = "Allied Telesis AT-9000/28SP";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.171.10.117.1.3")
                {$id = 105;$sysobject = "D-Link DGS-3120-24SC";}

            # 1000-9999 ups
            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.2254.2.4")
                {$id = 1000;$sysobject = "Delta GES102R202035";}

            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.935")
                {$id = 1001;$sysobject = "EngPower EP901RH";}

            # 10000-99999 core
            if($sysobjectid eq ".1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.402")
                {$id = 10000;$sysobject = "Cisco 7606 Chassis";}
            }
            else
            {
            $id = "-1";
            print "fault, reason: wrong SNMP community or forbitten SNMP protocol ";
            }

        if($id eq 0){print "unknow net device ";}
        undef $snmptemp;

        if ($id >= 0)
            {
            #get MAC-adress
            $snmptemp = $snmpsession -> get_request(".1.3.6.1.2.1.17.1.1.0");
            $localmac = $snmptemp -> {".1.3.6.1.2.1.17.1.1.0"};

            #get sysLocation.0
            $snmptemp = $snmpsession -> get_request(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0");
            $syslocation = $snmptemp -> {".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0"};

            #get sysName.0
            $snmptemp = $snmpsession -> get_request(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0");
            $sysname = $snmptemp -> {".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0"};

            #get VLAN
            $snmptemp = $snmpsession -> get_request(".1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.4.3.1.1");
            $vlanid = $snmptemp -> {".1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.4.3.1.1"};

            # Take Loopback0 for aggregator
            if($id >= 100 && $id <= 999)
                {
                $snmptemp = $snmpsession -> get_request(".1.3.6.1.2.1.14.1.1.0");
                $snmploopback = $snmptemp -> {".1.3.6.1.2.1.14.1.1.0"};
                $iphost = $snmploopback;
                }

            #LLDP nei
                %snmplldpnei_hash = %{$snmpsession -> get_table(".1.0.8802.1.1.2.1.4.1.1.5")};
                my $snmpport;
                foreach $lldpneioid (keys %snmplldpnei_hash)
                    {
                    $lldpneioid =~ m/(\d{1,})(?=\.(\d{1,})$)/;
                    if($id >=0 && $id <= 999)
                        {
                        $getport = ".1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1."."$&";
                        $snmptemp = $snmpsession -> get_request("$getport");
                        $portname = $snmptemp -> {"$getport"};
                        $edges{$edgesid} = {
                        'edgefrom'=>$localmac,
                        'edgeto'=>$snmplldpnei_hash{$lldpneioid},
                        'port'=>$portname,
                        };
                        $edgesid = $edgesid + 1;
                        $lldpnei.= $portname."->".$snmplldpnei_hash{$lldpneioid}.",";
                        }
                    }
                if(defined($lldpnei))
                    {
                    chop $lldpnei;
                    }



            # take firmware for D-Link DES-3200-26 ...
            if ($id == 2 || $id == 5 || $id == 9 || $id == 10 || $id == 11 )
                {
                $snmptemp = $snmpsession -> get_request(".1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.9.1");
                $fw = $snmptemp -> {".1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.9.1"};
                }

            # take firmware for D-Link DES-3526 ...
            if ($id == 4)
                {
                $snmptemp = $snmpsession -> get_request(".1.3.6.1.2.1.16.19.2.0");
                $fw = $snmptemp -> {".1.3.6.1.2.1.16.19.2.0"};
                }
            }

        if(!defined($fw))
            {
            $fw = "";
            }

        if($id >=0 )
            {
            print "$iphost;";
            print "$localmac;";
            print "$syslocation;";
            print "$vlanid;";
            print "$sysname;";
            print "$id;";
            print "$sysobject;";
            print "$fw;";

            if(!defined($lldpnei))
                {
                $lldpnei = "";
                }

            print "$lldpnei\n\n";
            $database{$iphost}={
            'localmac'=>$localmac,
            'syslocation'=>$syslocation,
            'vlanid'=>$vlanid,
            'sysname'=>$sysname,
            'id'=>$id,
            'sysobject'=>$sysobject,
            'lldpnei'=>$lldpnei,
            'fw'=>$fw,
            };
            }

        undef $fw;
        undef $localmac;
        undef $syslocation;
        undef $vlanid;
        undef $sysname;
        undef $id;
        undef $sysobject;
        undef $lldpnei;
        }
    %hosts = (); 
    }

my $edgefrom;
my $edgefrom2;
my $edgeto;
my $edgeto2;
my $edge;
my $edge2;
my $port;
my $port2;

foreach $edge6(keys %edges)
    {
    $edgefrom6 = $edges{$edge6}{edgefrom};
    $edgeto6 = $edges{$edge6}{edgeto};
    $port6 = $edges{$edge6}{port};
    print "$edge6 => $edgefrom6--$edgeto6;$port6\n";
    }

# delete full edges dublicate
foreach $edge3(keys %edges)
    {
    $edgefrom3 = $edges{$edge3}{edgefrom};
    $edgeto3 = $edges{$edge3}{edgeto};
    $port3 = $edges{$edge3}{port};
    if(defined($edgefrom3) & defined($edgeto3) & defined($port3))
        {
        foreach $edge4(keys %edges)
            {
            $edgefrom4 = $edges{$edge4}{edgefrom};
            $edgeto4 = $edges{$edge4}{edgeto};
            $port4 = $edges{$edge4}{port};
            if(defined($edgefrom4) & defined($edgeto4) & defined($port4))
                {           
                if($edgefrom3 eq $edgefrom4 & $edgeto3 eq $edgeto4 & $port3 eq $port4 & $edge3 ne $edge4)
                    {
                    delete $edges{$edge4};
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

# combine edges and ports and delete dublicate
foreach $edge(keys %edges)
    {
    my $port2;
    $edgefrom = $edges{$edge}{edgefrom};
    $edgeto = $edges{$edge}{edgeto};
    $port = $edges{$edge}{port};
    foreach $edge2(keys %edges)
        {
        $edgefrom2 = $edges{$edge2}{edgefrom};
        $edgeto2 = $edges{$edge2}{edgeto};
        if(defined($edgefrom))
            {
            if(defined($edgeto2))
                {
                if($edgefrom eq $edgeto2)
                    {
                    if($edgeto eq $edgefrom2)
                        {
                        $port2 = $edges{$edge2}{port};
                        delete $edges{$edge2};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    if (defined($edgefrom) & defined($edgeto))
        {
        if(defined($edge) & defined($edgefrom) & defined($edgeto) & defined($port) & defined($port2))
            {
            print "$edge => $edgefrom--$edgeto;$port;$port2\n";
            }
        if(!defined($port2))
            {
            $port2 = "";
            }
        $lldpmap.= "\"$edgefrom\" -- \"$edgeto\" [taillabel=\"$port\", headlabel=\"$port2\", labeldistance=\"8\", len=\"15\" ]\;\n";
        }
    }

foreach $iphost(keys %database)
    {
    $fw = $database{$iphost}{fw};
    $syslocation = $database{$iphost}{syslocation};
    $vlanid = $database{$iphost}{vlanid};
    $sysname = $database{$iphost}{sysname};
    $sysobject = $database{$iphost}{sysobject};
    $id = $database{$iphost}{id};   
    $localmac = $database{$iphost}{localmac};
    my @portmac = ();

    if($id >= 0 && $id <= 9999)
        {
        $label.="\"$database{$iphost}{localmac}\" [ label=\"$iphost\\n$syslocation\\n$sysobject\\n$sysname\\n$vlanid\", fillcolor=\"white\", shape=\"$shape\", ranksep=\"15\" ]\;\n";
        }
    }

open(lldp2dot,">mapdot.gv");
print lldp2dot "graph lldp2dot {\n\toverlap=scale;\n\tsplines=true;\n";
print lldp2dot "node [ shape=\"box\", fixedsize=\"false\", style=\"filled\", fillcolor=\"black\" ];\n";
print lldp2dot "graph [ fontname=\"Helvetica-Oblique\", fontsize=\"150\", label=\"Metro\", size=\"12\" ];\n";
print lldp2dot "edge [color=red];\n";
print lldp2dot $label;
print lldp2dot $lldpmap;
print lldp2dot "}";
close(lldp2dot);

sub pingDec {
    my $iphost=iptools::dectoIP(shift);
    print "ping $iphost...";
    if($ping->ping($iphost,0.500))
        {
        $hosts{$iphost}=undef;
        print " success, save result, go to next host...\n";
        }
        else
        {
        print " fault, save result, go to next host...\n";
        }
    return 0;
}

# pdf

#print "dot ==> generation PDF...\n";
#`dot -Tpdf -Gratio=auto -Ecolor=black -Ncolor=black -Goverlap=false -Gsize=20 mapdot.gv -o mapdot_06.08.13.pdf`;

print "neato ==> generation PDF...\n";
`neato -Tpdf -Gratio=auto -Ecolor=black -Ncolor=black -Goverlap=false -Gsize=20 mapdot.gv -o mapneato_$today.pdf`;

#print "fdp ==> generation PDF...\n";
#`fdp -Tpdf -Gratio=auto -Ecolor=black -Ncolor=black -Goverlap=false -Gsize=20 mapdot.gv -o mapfdp.pdf`;

# svg

# print "dot ==> generation SVG...\n";
# `dot -Tsvg -Gratio=auto -Ecolor=black -Ncolor=black -Goverlap=false -Gsize=10 mapdot.gv -o mapdot.svg`;

print "neato ==> generation PS2...\n";
`neato -Tsvg -Gratio=auto -Ecolor=black -Ncolor=black -Goverlap=false -Gsize=20 mapdot.gv -o mapneato_$today.svg`;

# print "fdp ==> generation SVG...\n";
# `fdp -Tsvg -Gratio=auto -Ecolor=black -Ncolor=black -Goverlap=false -Gsize=50 mapdot.gv -o mapfdp.svg`;
```

Я предполагаю, что проблема вот в этом куске:

```
my @scanRange = (
    "10.111.1.4-10.111.1.4, 10.101.1.6-10.101.1.6"  
);
foreach my $rangeS (@scanRange)
{
    my @range = split /-/, $rangeS;
    my $startIP = iptools::IPtodec($range[0]);
    my $endIP = iptools::IPtodec($range[1]);
    for (my $i = $startIP; $i <= $endIP; $i++)
    {
        $_->join() foreach (threads->list(threads::joinable));
        if (threads->list(threads::all) > $maxThreads)
        {
            print "thread count > limit, joining\n";
            while (threads->list(threads::all) > $maxThreads)
            {
                $_->join() foreach (threads->list(threads::joinable));
            }
        }
        threads->create(\&pingDec, $i);
    }
    while (threads->list(threads::all))
    {
        $_->join() foreach (threads->list(threads::joinable));
    }
    foreach $iphost (keys %hosts)
    {
        print "get sysObjct.0 from $iphost... \n";
    }
```

Comment: Я не уверен что тут можно переписать какой то определенный кусок

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `"10.199.1.4-10.199.1.4, 10.199.1.6-10.199.1.6"` на `"10.199.1.4-10.199.1.4", "10.199.1.6-10.199.1.6"`.

Comment: пробовал, не помогает

Comment: 1. вы привели ссылку на сайт, а там требуется регистрация даже для прочтения. это, вероятно, не совсем правильно. 2. в самом начале подключается некий `./libs`, а вы не предоставили ни исходников этого файла(-ов), ни ссылки для их скачивания. это, вероятно, тоже не совсем правильно.

Comment: Помогло!!! Спасибо!

Comment: Ссылку поправил

Comment: my @scanRange=(
 "10.199.1.4-10.199.1.4", "10.109.17.121-10.109.17.121" 
);

Comment: Скорей всего чтото не так делал до этого

Comment: Размещайте, приму.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my @scanRange = ("10.111.1.4-10.111.1.4, 10.101.1.6-10.101.1.6");
```

представляет собой массив, состоящий из одного элемента (строки). В результате в `foreach my $rangeS (@scanRange)` будет всего одна итерация, в которой в `@range` окажутся строки `"10.111.1.4"` , `"10.111.1.4, 10.101.1.6"` и `"10.101.1.6"`.

В то время как

```
my @scanRange = ("10.111.1.4-10.111.1.4", "10.101.1.6-10.101.1.6");
```

даст массив из двух элементов, в каждом из которых - один диапазон.

Comment: Удобнее будет написать `my @scanRange = qw/10.111.1.4-10.111.1.4 10.101.1.6-10.101.1.6/`. Если подсетей много - устанете ставить кавычки, ну и как-то более в стиле perl что-ли.

Comment: @andy.37 я, кстати, последнее время многие "перловые штуки" заменяю в коде на более привычные для Java и C# (без учета новомодных штуки вроде лямбда-выражений и LINQ). Думаю, если подсетей будет много, то автор устанет их писать в любом случае).